# Personal First Person Cameras for each Player using Unity's 'Netcode for GameObjects'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning how to use Netcode for GameObjects and have just gotten the client, host, and server working as well as a movement script for the players that only effects each player individually. the only problem with it now is that when a new player is spawned, any existing players camera is changed to the camera that is spawned within the prefab of the new player. I have looked around online for a solution and [this is the closest thing I could find](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYqJWb356aA) but it's not done using Netcode for GameObjects and I'm not sure how to translate the information in the video over.

Any idea how i could achieve this?

Comment: You can fix the issue by making each player's camera a child object of their GameObject and only setting the camera on the local player's GameObject as the main camera. Use the `NetworkIdentity` component to check if the player object is the local player, then set the main camera using `Camera.main` property. In your spawn function, make sure to disable the camera on the new player's prefab before it is instantiated, so it doesn't overwrite the main camera.

Comment: @zanderwar the players are spawned through the "Player Prefab" input of the Network Manager object, is there a way that i can access the spawn function of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that video, I'd imagine that you should be able to modify the "`OnStartAuthority`" method to the following

```
public override void OnNetworkSpawn() { // This is basically a Start method
    cameraHolder.SetActive(IsOwner);
    base.OnNetworkSpawn(); // Not sure if this is needed though, but good to have it.
}
```

To walk you through, When the player is spawned, the `OnNetworkSpawn()` is triggered, and then we activate the cameraHolder object based on the "`IsOwner`" property of `NetworkBehaviour`, and its value is based on if the local player "Owns" the object.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a single clientside `PlayerCamera` object, which, upon the player's own object spawning in, would be summoned and made to follow that object.

So, it would be something along the lines of:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

///<summary>The clientside class </summary>
public class PlayerCamera: MonoBehaviour
{
  ///<summary> the transform of the gameobject that the camera should be following</summary>
  [SerializeField]
  private Transform _target;

  ///<summary>our camera (attached to same gameobject)</summary>
  [SerializeField]
  private Camera _cam;

  //...

  void Awake()
  {
    _cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
  }

  ///<summary> obtains the target (or sets it + warps to the target)</summary>
  public Target
  {
    get { return _target;}
    set {
       _target = value;
       GoToTarget();
    }
  }

  ///<summary>scuffed example for getting the camera to stay with the target object</summary>
  private void GoToTarget()
  {
    if (_target == null) { return; }
    // TODO: make a better implementation
    transform.position = _target.position;
    transform.rotation = _target.rotation;
  }

  ///<summary>always stick with the target</summary>
  void Update()
  {
    GoToTarget();
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

And then in your player object, you would need something like this:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Unity.Netcode;

///<summary> the player object that the camera follows</summary>
public class PlayerObject: NetworkBehaviour
{

  ///<summary> reference to PlayerCamera that might be following this</summmary>
  private PlayerCamera _pCam;

  // ...

  ///<summary>
  ///this is called clientside by the owner in order to
  ///get their clientside camera to target this object
  ///</summary>
  private void WitnessMe()
  {
    if (!IsOwner){return;}
    // this object has the player camera
    _pCam = FindObjectOfType<PlayerCamera>();
    // and the player camera now targets this object's transform
    _pCam.Target = this.transform;
  }

  ///<summary>
  /// called clientside to get the camera to stop following this object.
  ///</summary>
  private void RemoveCamera()
  {
    if(_pCam != null)
    {
      _pCam.Target = null;
      _pCam = null;
    }

  }

  public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
  {
    // if this spawns in owned by the local player
    if (IsOwner)
    {
      WitnessMe(); // this object shall now be witnessed.
    }
    // ...

  }

  public override void OnGainedOwnership()
  {
    WitnessMe(); // we shall witness this upon gaining ownership of this.
    // ...
  }

  public override void OnNetworkDespawn()
  {
    RemoveCamera(); // no longer witnessed upon despawning
    // ...
  }

  public override void OnLostOwnership()
  {
    RemoveCamera(); // no longer witnessed if we no longer own it
    // ...
  }


}
```